# Fetch Telegram Post's views with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to fetch this number:

[image]

Tested this Telegram post:
https://t.me/s/google_sheets/393

I want to do it with a script. Interesting, it was possible for me to achieve this with a formula:

`=INDEX( REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA("https://t.me/s/google_sheets/393")),,2^99),CHAR(10),), "(.*tgme_widget_message_views"">)(.+)(<\/span><span class=""copyonly"".*)"),2)`

This is the script I've tried:

```
function GET() {
  var reg1 = /tgme_widget_message_views">(.+)<\/span><span class="copyonly"/i;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://t.me/s/google_sheets/393').getContentText();   
  var match = response.match(new RegExp(reg1))[1];           
  Logger.log(match); // 13.4K, expected: 11.2K
}
```

It gives me the wrong result. I'm willing to do the work with a script because I want an efficient way of fetching multiple URLs at once. The formula will crash in this situation.

My script gives me the wrong result, it may be the number for other Telegram post (https://t.me/google_sheets/374 ), I'm not sure. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure if you would like to consider this approach. But telegram has its own API:https://core.telegram.org/. Sorry if that does not help you at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the one you are looking for is that specific post and not the others, you may want to limit what you are searching for by appending the id of the post at the end of your regex. Thus we are sure we are looking just until post id 393. As you can see, I added `.+google_sheets\/393` in your regex.

```
function GET() {
  var reg1 = /tgme_widget_message_views">(.+)<\/span><span class="copyonly".+google_sheets\/393/i;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://t.me/s/google_sheets/393').getContentText();   

  var match = response.match(new RegExp(reg1))[1];           
  Logger.log(match); //11.2K
}
```